# Create New Data Frame with Column Names from Unique Values in another Data Frame and Corresponding Values Assigned to Column

Tags: r, reshape

I'm new to R, and I'm pretty sure this is something simple to accomplish, but I cannot figure out how to perform this action. I've tried the split function, utilizing a for loop, but cannot quite figure out how to get it right. As an example, this is what my original data frame looks like:

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = c(rep("red", 4), rep("blue", 3)), col2 = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9))

 col1 col2
  red    1
  red    3
  red    2
  red    4
 blue    7
 blue    8
 blue    9
```

I want to create new columns for each unique value in col1 and assign it's corressponding value in col2 to the new data frame. And this is how I want my new data frame:

```
red  blue
 1       7
 3       8
 2       9
 4      NA
```

I've gotten close with a list structure close to what I wanted, but I need a data frame to boxplot and dotplot the results. Any help would be appriciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure there's a more efficient solution, but here's one option

```
dat <- data.frame(col1 = c(rep("red", 4), rep("blue", 3)), col2 = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9))
dat

  col1 col2
1  red    1
2  red    3
3  red    2
4  red    4
5 blue    7
6 blue    8
7 blue    9    

ust <- unstack(dat, form = col2 ~ col1)
res <- data.frame(sapply(ust, '[', 1:max(unlist(lapply(ust, length)))))
res
  blue red
1    7   1
2    8   3
3    9   2
4   NA   4
```

Edit:  If you want the column order red then blue

```
res[, c("red", "blue")]
  red blue
1   1    7
2   3    8
3   2    9
4   4   NA
```

Comment: hmmm `unstack`, never heard of this one

Comment: I’m using it to plot out patient scheduled appointment wait times by each clinic at my hospital, and it’s already helped by giving us a view we’ve never had before in identifying the specific problem clinics. Our patients will be thankful as well!!

Comment: Great news!  Since this solution is working for you, you can click the check mark by the question to accept.  This gives reputation points to me and you also (I think) :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an Hadleyverse possible solution

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  spread(col1, col2)
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# 
#   n blue red
# 1 1    7   1
# 2 2    8   3
# 3 3    9   2
# 4 4   NA   4
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat)[, indx := 1:.N, by = col1], indx ~ col1, value.var = "col2")
#    indx blue red
# 1:    1    7   1
# 2:    2    8   3
# 3:    3    9   2
# 4:    4   NA   4
```

Comment: Am I right in saying that you always need a "row identifier column" (here: n) to make it work with dplyr?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you *always need*, it's just the solution I came up with. Hence the "*possible*" at the top.

Comment: Sure. I guess it just doesn't happen too often that I try to cast data that I haven't melted before.

Comment: Yes, this data misses the "Variable" column I guess.

Comment: @maj There's a feature request open for omitting it: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1205

Answer (score 0):

Just to show another option using base R `*apply`and `cbind`

```
# split the data into list using col1 column
tmp.list   = lapply(split(dat, dat$col1), function(x) x$col2)

# identify the length of the biggest list
max.length = max(sapply(tmp.list, length))

# combine the list elements, while filling NA for the missing values
data.frame(do.call(cbind, 
  lapply(tmp.list, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max.length - length(x))))
))

#  blue red
#1    7   1
#2    8   3
#3    9   2
#4   NA   4
```