# Taking values from an 'answer key' dataframe based on matching 2 variables in 1 dataframe to the 'key' in the 'answer key' dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I can't think of a way to concisely or effectively phrase this, but this is what I want to do...

**I have the following :**

1. Dataframe of interest with columns (amongst others):

$first_name: "DONALD", "BARACK", "GEORGE", "BILL", ...

$last_name:  "TRUMP", "OBAMA", "BUSH", "CLINTON", ...

and

2. An "answer key" dataframe:

$name: "Donald John, TRUMP", "Barack Hussein, OBAMA", "Bill Jefferson, CLINTON", "George Walker, BUSH", ...

$value: 0, 2, 4, 6, ...

**I want:**

$first_name: "DONALD", "BARACK", "GEORGE", "BILL", ...

$last_name: "TRUMP", "OBAMA", "BUSH", "CLINTON", ...

$value: 0, 2, 4, 6, ...

**It's important to note that:**

1. There is no way of knowing the metaphorical middle names from the "answer key" dataframe (without visually inspecting thousands of columns).
2. The names are not lined up the same (in contrast to how I have displayed it).
3. The $first_name and $last_names's are repeated within the dataframe of interest.

**So far**

I've managed to get the $first_name's to be in the same format as they are in $name (**that is, I now have "Bill" and "CLINTON", but I can't figure out how to connect them to "Bill Jefferson, CLINTON" <- 6** ). I originally planned on using grep() somehow to match them, but I don't think that is possible because it doesn't seem that you can use a vector for "pattern =".

These two seem relevant, at least in concept, but I'm just drawing a blank.

[Create New Data Frame with Column Names from Unique Values in another Data Frame and Corresponding Values Assigned to Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236327/create-new-data-frame-with-column-names-from-unique-values-in-another-data-frame)

[Define the value of a column in a dataframe based on 2 keys from a different dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41696374/define-the-value-of-a-column-in-a-dataframe-based-on-2-keys-from-a-different-dat)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We extract the substring from the second dataset, do a `match` and use that to get the 'value'

```
df1$value <- df2$value[match(do.call(paste, df1), toupper(sub("\\s+\\w+,", "", df2$name)))]
df1
#    first_name last_name value
#1     DONALD     TRUMP     0
#2     BARACK     OBAMA     2
#3     GEORGE      BUSH     6
#4       BILL   CLINTON     4
```

#### data

```
 df1 <- data.frame(first_name = c("DONALD", "BARACK", "GEORGE", "BILL"), 
  last_name = c("TRUMP", "OBAMA", "BUSH", "CLINTON"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 df2 <- data.frame(name = c("Donald John, TRUMP", "Barack Hussein, OBAMA",
  "Bill Jefferson, CLINTON",
     "George Walker, BUSH"), value = c(0, 2, 4, 6) , stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: You are a saint/wizard. Thank you.

Comment: @J.Diaz  I spent some time on coding daily.  If you practise coding, you could become good in it.